# MySQL Process taking unusually huge time

Tags: mysql

I have got a task that runs hourly, and have been running for a few months now. The process takes analytics from the MySQL (MariaDB) and aggregates the data. It usually takes between 1-5 minutes to finish.

However since only 13 hours ago, it is now taking 26 minutes out of nowhere. I have restarted the MySQL server, nothing changed. The processlist shows that the aggregation is responsible for the long time (some queries are taking unusually 500 seconds to complete, they used to take less than 30 seconds).

The table I am querying is 26 million rows big.

What could have caused this jump of processing time out of nowhere? It has been working fine for a long time!

What do you suggest I do now? Could the database have gone corrupt?

Queries:

```
*************************** 2. row ***************************
      Id: 76042556
    User: -----
    Host: --------
      db: mydb
 Command: Query
    Time: 456
   State: Sending data
    Info: SELECT avg(analytics.event) AS `avg_session`, count(*) AS `count` FROM `analytics` WHERE `analytics`.`app_id` = '436' AND `analytics`.`event_type` = 'session' AND `analytics`.`created_at` >= '2015-06-19 12:16:41' AND `analytics`.`created_at` <= '2015-07-19 12:16:41' ORDER BY `analytics`.`id` ASC
Progress: 0.000
```

Explain:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT `analytics`.`event` AS `event`, `analytics`.`created_at` AS `a_created_at`, EXTRACT(DAY FROM analytics.created_at) AS `interval`, count(analytics.id) AS `count` FROM `analytics` WHERE `analytics`.`app_id` = '436' AND `analytics`.`event_type` = 'startup' AND `analytics`.`created_at` >= '2015-06-21 09:32:41' AND `analytics`.`created_at` <= '2015-07-21 09:32:41' GROUP BY `interval` ORDER BY `a_created_at` ASC
    -> ;
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref   | rows     | filtered | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | analytics | ref  | app_id        | app_id | 5       | const | 15236882 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

P.S: Kindly, do not lecture me about how to cut back on long queries rather than to help me understand this specific problem.

Comment: Can you post your query here?

Comment: The query has been added

Comment: What's your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value? It could be that MariaDB can't fit the dataset in the memory and is using the disk to find the records that it's supposed to aggregate - unusually long times to do something in world of databases almost always means they're I/O constrained. In case of a mechanical disk, this means that your setup becomes slow as snail, to the point where it's almost faster to calculate stuff by hand. Do verify that your data fits the memory, and if possible (and you don't have one) - try to use an SSD for permanent storage opposed to a mechanical drive.

Answer (score 0):

I think that You can try:

- optimize table(s)
- repair table(s) - data may be corrupted in fact or maybe there are some overloads
- check locks: maybe some more inserts is executed on the table(s)
  queried by an aggregate queries (maybe some functionalities has been
  added recently and users more often submits forms...)

I assume that indexes are well defined and database structure was not updated by someone else without Your knowledge ;)

Comment: I am using InnoDB engine, so there is no repair function, but only dumping and restoring.

Comment: ah - ok - so maybe this will help (if table corruption is source of the problem...): https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/07/04/recovering-innodb-table-corruption/

Comment: How would I know if it is corrupt? Is there a status variable to indicate so? Because everything is working fine (Except the 5x query time that has just occured)

Comment: status variable - I think not ;) but copying it to myisam and run the query on it,  should give You some comparison and maybe will lead to some clue...
is that query the only one which suddenly started to be looooonger then it was on that table? is this the only query which causes problems on that table now?  are You sure NOTHING was changed in the query before it became slow? btw. I see that you've added explain result - but explained query is different then the problematic one - why?

Comment: and one more thing: is it always such date range? if from-to dates/times are the same, you can just set `analytics`.`created_at` = '{datetime}' instead of checking range - and (as it is suggested above) try to remove order by

Comment: Yes it is always a month date range. I will try what you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Few Suggestions

1. Remove Order by clause as it does not do any good for this query
2. Add proper indexes based on your nature of data. Could be `app_id`.
3. If too many updates/deletes are fired in `analytics`, the do `optimize table analytics`. This will re structure your indexes

It will help us if you post your `explain` result also

Comment: I have added the explain and I optimized the table. Optimization didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Index on app_id does not seem to help you. So you may try creating a composite index of app_id, event_type, created at. This would give you the maximum performance. However you will face some issue if you have frequent inserts . Have you configured your innodb buffer pool size adequately?